# Merge two strings with alternate chars as output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got the task to alternately combine the letters of two strings with the same length.

For example:

```
Inputstring 1: "acegi"

Inputstring 2: "bdfhj"

Outputstring: "abcdefghij"
```

And I got the following Problem when I run my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "...", line 14, in <module>
    x =x+f
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

I think every relevant variable is a `String`.

```
s=str(input("Input first String:"))
v=str(input("Input second String:"))
x=""
c=1
z=""
f=""
laenge=len(s)
lenge=len(v)

for f in range(laenge):

    if f in range(c,c+1):
        x =x+f
for z in range(lenge):

    if z in range(c,c+1):
        x=x+z
c=c+1

print(x)
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string, you don't need to use `str()` around it.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Could you explain your code? I see several issues. What are you trying to accomplish? I suggest a complete rewrite instead of fixing the `TypeError`.

Comment: Post detailed error message please. On which line of code?

Comment: `if f in range(c, c+1):` is the same as `if f = c:`.

Comment: Your inner loop variable rewrites the outer loop one.

Comment: `x = x + f` is the problem. `x` is a string, `f` is a number. You can't add them.

Comment: Your question title is wholly inadequate; a very large percentage of Python questions deal with string issues. In future, please come up with one that better covers *your specific situation*.

Comment: I've also added a nominal traceback. Notice how that traceback includes the actual line that the exception is thrown at? That is *important information* that helps us avoid guessing.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it in one line using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
out1 = ''.join(''.join(f for f in tup) for tup in zip(inp1, inp2))
```

**or** the more functional-style:

```
out1 = ''.join(map(''.join, zip(inp1, inp2)))  # kudos @Coldspeed
```

which both print

```
abcdefghij
```

---

Braking the code down:

- `zip()`

  ```
  pairs = list(zip(inp1, inp2))
  print(pairs )  # [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h'), ('i', 'j')]
  ```
- `.join()`

  ```
  temp = []
  for sub in pairs:
      temp.append(''.join(sub))
  print(temp)  # ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij']
  ```
- `.join()` again

  ```
  out1 = ''.join(temp)
  print(out1)  # abcdefghij
  ```

---

Finally, and for your entertainment and learning only, two additional, more *old-school* approaches:

```
out1 = ''
for i in range(len(inp1)):
    out1 += inp1[i] + inp2[i]
```

and

```
out1 = ''
for i, c in enumerate(inp1):
    out1 += c + inp2[i]
```

Answer (score 5):

One can simply use `map` with `join` to get desired result:

```
"".join(map(lambda x,y: x+y, astr, bstr))
```

`zip` in not needed here since 2 strings/lists can be provided to `map` which has a lambda function that takes 2 arguments. Also, `+` symbol works to concatenate 2 strings here.

Answer (score 3):

One of the first things you should learn when programming is to use meaningful variable names, not cryptic, 1-letter names.

Your code is not alternating between the two input strings. You're looping through the first string, then looping through the second string, and never repeating.

I'm not sure what the point of the `c` variable is. You set it to `1` at the beginning of the script, then add 1 to it later, but then the script ends. Was there supposed to be another loop around all that code?

The loop that checks if `f` is in `range(c, c+1)` could just be `f = c`, there's no point to looping.

The error is coming from

```
x = x + f
```

because `x` is a string and `f` is an `int`. I suspect you wanted to do `x = x + s[f]`.

The whole thing can be simplified greatly.

```
string1 = input("Enter string 1: ")
len1 = len(string1)
string2 = input("enter string 2: ")
len2 = len(string2)
if len1 != len2:
    print("Inputs must be the same length")
else:
    result = ""
    for i in range(len1):
        result += string1[i]
        result += string2[i]
    print(result)
```

Comment: I'm sure that the OP had meant for there to be an outer loop involving `c` some how and the code for appending should have been like: `x = x + s[f]`. Anyway, your code is *much* simpler!

Comment: Further simplification: `''.join(map(''.join, zip(string1, string2)))`

Comment: Isn't concatenating strings with `+=` quadratic? appending to a list then using `join()` would be linear.

Comment: @RoadRunner Clarity is more important than efficiency for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code. The one that is the most important is your naming problem. Give meaningful names to your variables.

Now, to the logic. You need to **iterate** through your strings at the same time, or use an index on both at the same time, and not one after the other.

You could do as such, for a more pythonic way of doing this.

```
first = input("Your first string.")
second = input("Your second string.")

if len(first) != len(second):
    print 'Bad length for the inputs.'
else:
    newString = ""
    for s1, s2 in zip(first, second):
        newString += s1 + s2
    print newString
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a and b with input or however you want. No need to copy that. The point is the code.

```
a = 'acegi'
b = 'bdfhj'

c = ''
for i in range(len(a)):
    c += a[i] + b[i]

print(c)
```

Result is:

```
abcdefghij
```